# How to help LUIS detect "half a mile", "a quarter of a pound", etc

Tags: azure, nlp, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am creating a fitness app and need to get the following entities from utterances like this:

```
"I just ran a mile" --> number ="1", dimension = "miles"
"I gained half a pound" --> number = "0.5", dimension = "pounds"
"I walked a quarter of a mile" --> number ="0.25", dimension = "miles"
```

Currently, it only recognizes the words "mile" and "pound" as dimensions, but I can't get it to recognize the fractions. I am new to LUIS; could I get some advice on the best way/best practices to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that LUIS app can not help recognize and convert "a" to "1" ("half a" to "0.5" and "a quarter of a" to "0.25" etc) directly, if possible, you can maintain a mapping table or dictionary of "a quarter of a"=>"0.25" etc, and then you can extract the matched entity (or query) and get corresponding number by retrieving mapping table.

Comment: Thank you, @FeiHan. Is the dictionary/mapping table something I can do directly in LUIS (so that the answer sent back to the API is already formatted this way) or would we have to parse the utterance again in the backend looking for these patterns?

Comment: Also, for those who are in the same situation - Using "two and a half miles", for example, is recognized and converted to numbers. It's only a problem when the expression doesn't start with a whole number: "half a pound", "a quarter of a mile", etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use prebuilt entities.[LUIS.ai](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5K3p.png)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am already using the Number entity and it is not detecting  it. Ordinals, as far as I understand, is for a different purpose and does not include fractions of numbers, just ordinals.

Comment: Good. You also can try then to create **phrase list** in LUIS and add values that  are interchangeable (like half and 0.5).

Comment: Hi @Irina! I actually spoke to the LUIS dev team today regarding what you mentioned, and they believe it is actually a bug with the prebuilt entity, if you are using prebuilt entities. As you mentioned, it was able to detect fractions so long as the number began with a whole number and not the fraction itself--this is not the intended behavior. The team wanted to verify so we know where to apply the fix, are you using English culture?

Comment: Hi @Zeryth, that's great news! Yes, I am using English culture. Please notice that time fractions ("half an hour", for example) work fine, so it is not a problem for the prebuilt datetimeV2.duration entity, just the dimension entity. Thanks!

Comment: Also, @Zeryth - I have noticed that  LUIS does not label dL (the abbreviation for deciliters) as a dimension, and won't allow me to label it as such. This is a problem when recognizing blood sugar levels (measured as mg/dL) for fitness applications, since LUIS recognizes mg as a dimension but not dL. Is there any plans to add this, or to let the user label words as a prebuilt entity and retrain the model? I apologize for mentioning this off-topic issue here but I didn't know of any other place to post it. Thanks!

Comment: @Irina with regards to prebuilt entities, you can post bugs directly to the team that develops it here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Recognizers-Text

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you so much, @Zeryth!